# Solve a polynomial in connection with the numerical solution of diffusion equation by finite volume

Tags: polynomials, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, algorithms, finite-differences

Hope everybody is safe during this COVID-19 pandemic!

I am having an issue numerically solving the following coupled diffusion equation with concentration dependent coefficients and need some suggestions on possible work arounds. The transport equation I wish to solve is:

$$
\theta^B\frac{\partial c_i^B}{\partial t} + \theta^D\frac{\partial c_i^D}{\partial t} =\theta^B\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(J_i^B\right) + \theta^D\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(J_i^D\right).
$$

This an equation for diffusion of charged ions in a dual continuum system representative of charged porous media (e.g., membrane, clay). The superscript B and D refers to the properties at "bulk water" and "Donnan water" porosities, respectively. Considering a Donnan equilibrium, the concentrations and fluxes  in these sub-domains are related as,

$$
c_i^D = c_i^Bexp\left(\frac{-z_iF\psi^D}{RT}\right) = c_i^D {BF}^{z_i} \\
J_i^B = -D_i^B\frac{\partial c_i^B}{\partial x} + \frac{z_iD_i^Bc_i^B}{\sum_j^N\left(z_j^2 D_j^B c_j^B\right)}\sum_j^N\left(z_jD_j^B\frac{\partial c_i^B}{\partial x}\right) \\ = \sum_j^N \left[\delta_{ijD_i^B} - \frac{z_iz_jD_i^BD_j^Bc_i^B}{\sum_j^N\left(z_j^2 D_j^B c_j^B\right)}\right]\frac{\partial c_i^B}{\partial x} \\
J_i^D = -D_i^D\frac{\partial c_i^D}{\partial x} + \frac{z_iD_i^Dc_i^D}{\sum_j^N\left(z_j^2 D_j^D c_j^D\right)}\sum_j^N\left(z_jD_j^D\frac{\partial c_i^D}{\partial x}\right) \\ = -D_i^D\frac{\partial ({BF}^{z_i} c_i^B)}{\partial x} + \frac{z_iD_i^D {BF}^{z_i} c_i^B}{\sum_j^N\left(z_j^2 D_j^D {BF}^{z_i} c_j^B\right)}\sum_j^N\left(z_jD_j^D\frac{\partial ({BF}^{z_i} c_i^B)}{\partial x}\right) \\ = \sum_j^N \left[\delta_{ijD_i^B}{BF}^{z_i} - \frac{z_iz_jD_i^BD_j^B{BF}^{z_i}{BF}^{z_j}c_i^B}{\sum_j^N\left(z_j^2 D_j^B {BF}^{z_i} c_j^B\right)}\right]\frac{\partial c_i^B}{\partial x}
$$

Using these relationships, the above transport equation can be discretized with finite difference method, and using a backward Euler scheme, it can be represented in the following in the discretized form:

$$
\theta^B(\textbf{c}_i^{B,t+dt} -\textbf{c}_i^{B,t}) + \theta^D(\textbf{c}_i^{B,t+dt}\textbf{BF}^{z_i,t+dt} -\textbf{c}_i^{D,t}) = \textbf{M}^{t+dt}\textbf{c}_i^{B,t+dt} \\
(\theta^B + \theta^D \textbf{BF}^{z_i,t+dt} - \textbf{M}^{t+dt}) \textbf{c}_i^{B,t+dt} = (\theta^B\textbf{c}_i^{B,t} + \theta^D\textbf{c}_i^{D,t}) \\
$$

Where, $\textbf{M}$ contains all the cross-coupled flux entries for the finite difference method. Now this system of algebraic equations can be solved using the direct matrix solver. I have implemented these calculations in MATLAB and solve the above system of equations by "blackslash" function of matlab. However, the system of equations is highly nonlinear because both $\textbf{M}$ and $\textbf{BF}^{z_i}$ are dependent on the concentration $\textbf{c}$. To determine the so called "Boltzmann factor" (BF), two additional constraints, related to the electroneutrality of Donnan and bulk porosities, need to be considered:

$$
\text{in bulk water: }\sum_i^N z_ic_i^B = 0\\
\text{in Donnan water: }\sum_i^N z_ic_i^D + Q = 0 \\
\sum_i^N z_i{BF}^{z_i}c_i^B + Q = 0
$$
Here Q is the surface charge in the Donnan water and can be considered a constant in this case.

My problem is related to the effective solution of the above polynomial to determine BF. So far, I have implemented a Picard iterative loop to solve the system of equations. For a particular time step, the steps inside the loop is:

while loop

- step 1: Calculate BF by the solving $\sum_i^N z_i{BF}^{z_i}c_i^B + Q = 0$
- step 2: Calculate flux entries including diffusion parameters (entries of $\text{M}$)
- step 3: Form the matrix $\text{M}$
- step 4: Solve for concentration

end

Iteration continues until the concentration converges to a threshold. However, this approach does not and the iterative scheme is not able to update both $\textbf{c}$ and $\textbf{BF}$ ! The above steps seem to work without any error but the Boltmann factor stays the same and does not change as the concentration changes. So far, I have tried two matlab functions (fzero, and roots) to solve $\sum_i^N z_i{BF}^{z_i}c_i^B + Q = 0$, where:

- fzero crashes as it sometimes produces the complex or undesired root (especially for the cubic and higher order polynomial cases)
- roots works without crashing, and it is possible to manually screen the positive root (BF is always positive), but still it does not properly update BF in the iteration.

I wonder if this problem with BF is related to the fact that c and BF appear as multiplication form in the equation?

Please note that, for a system containing only one symmetrical electrolyte (charge, z = 1 and -1), $\sum_i^Nz_i{BF}^{z_i}c_i^B + Q = 0$ reduces to a quadrtic equation. In this condition, analytical solution for BF exists. If I plug in this solution in the iterative scheme, the calculation works and both concentration and Boltzmann factor is properly updated.

But for systems containing multivalent ions (z_i>=2), $ \sum_i^Nz_i{BF}^{z_i}c_i^B + Q = 0$ takes the form of cubic or higher order polynomials. In such cases, analytical solution does not exist and the numerical solution as used with the matlab functions does not work :(

Can anybody suggest any tips or tricks to resolve this issue? Sorry for the long post but I would really appreciate any suggestions as I am stuck!

Thank you

Comment: I can't help really, but something that can help sometimes is reformulating the root-finding problem as a minimisation of the square of the function (watch for local minima of course). Alternatively if you code up some kind of Newton/quasi-Newton method you will have a bit control to tune the algorithm to avoid bad cases.